# Lodash orderBy returning empty array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to order an array with Objects in ascending order using lodash.orderBy npm module.

this is the example object I am using

```
var obj = [{ user: 'me', score: 100}, { user: 'you', score: 55}, { user: 'someone', score: 555 }]
```

Once I have that object, I pass it through as the first parameter and specify which key to orderBy.

```
let sort = orderBy(obj, 'score')
```

But this returns an empty array, is there something I am doing wrong ? based on the documentation this is correct: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy

This may be an issue with the asynchronous call and saying the index of the Array is 0.

**EDIT:**

[image]

[image: Expanded]

Comment: Are you importing `lodash` somewhere ? You should use `lodash.orderBy`, not the function by itself.

Comment: @Valberthe correct, I am importing eg import orderBy from 'lodash.orderby'

Comment: You have to be doing something wrong, because your example is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are not actually calling `orderBy()` on the `lodash` object. Try the following code:

**JS**

```
const _ = require('lodash');

var obj = [[{
    user: 'me',
    score: 100
},{
    user: 'you',
    score: 55
},{
    user: 'someone',
    score: 555
}]]

var data = obj[0];

let sort = _.orderBy(data, 'score');

console.log(sort);
```

Created a new variable `data` and assign it the value of `obj[0]` effectively assigning it the array. Lodash can then order the data as expected.

**Console Output** (score in ascending order by default)

```
  [ { user: 'you', score: 55 },
  { user: 'me', score: 100 },
  { user: 'someone', score: 555 } ]
```

**Possible solution for your code**

```
let obj = this.state.items;
let data = obj[0];
let sort = lodash.orderBy(data, 'score');
console.log(sort);
```

Comment: The orderBy itself works with static content, I believe the issue is because it's asynchronous data so, the array with 10 items logs as Array[0] not Array[9]

Comment: Are you using a callback?

Comment: It's a React web application using the Fetch api, so after the get request I set the state with the object returned and then log that out which returns Array[0] but it does have items inside of it.
I am thinking lodash is confused and thinks it's an empty array.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of one of the `object` expanded please

Comment: So all of the objects are being added to an array inside the array? @rizzy

Comment: I have a forEach that gets each of these articles, then push the response (objects) into an array using array.push(response)

Comment: @rizzy Check my latest answer update, I've just tried it, works for me, try and implement it to work with your solution :) If you need any help just ask

Comment: Unfortunately same issue, it must be related to the fetch requests. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @rizzy Are you sure that you are definitely calling `orderBy()` on the lodash object?

Comment: Sure did, it turns out when I add a setTimeout it works fine. Was related to the asynchronous calls and not having the data yet.

Comment: @rizzy Glad to hear you fixed it!

Comment: Thanks for all your help, i'll try find a way to give you positive feedback :)